# Ruby On Rails Mail Routine Not sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I Have a ROR IF statement that is supposed to look up a record and then send emails based on the login can anyone tell me what is wrong in the syntax?

this is now working but there is two test cases that return ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find SignOn with userw1 = xxx@example.com):
  app/models/order.rb:219:in `submit_order'

```
        class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

# NOTE: ensure that you always setup methods here to include and filter on
# query_account_number as a security measure.

establish_connection "web_#{RAILS_ENV}"
has_many :order_details, :dependent => :destroy, :order => 'id DESC'

def self.delete_item query_account_number, login, id
    order = Order.first(:conditions => {:account_number => query_account_number, :login => login})
    detail = order.order_details.first(:conditions => {:id => id})
    detail.destroy if detail
    # Here we would delete the order, but have chosen to leave it so they do not have
    # questionable gaps in IDs.
end

def self.verify_upc1 upc_rule, upc1
    "Invalid UPC Prefix" unless Item.first(:conditions => ["rul31c = ? AND CONCAT(TRIM(comi1c), 'A') = ?", upc_rule, upc1 + "A"],
        :select => "style")
end

def self.verify_upc2 upc_rule, upc1, upc2
    "Invalid UPC Prefix or Subnumber" unless Item.first(:conditions => ["rul31c = ? AND CONCAT(TRIM(comi1c), CONCAT(TRIM(arsb1c), 'A')) = ?", upc_rule, upc1 + upc2 + "A"],
        :select => "style")
end

def self.verify_style upc_rule, style
    "Invalid Style" unless Item.first(:conditions => ["rul31c = ? AND CONCAT(TRIM(style), 'A') = ?", upc_rule, style + "A"],
        :select => "style")
end

def self.update_quantity query_account_number, login, id, quantity
    if quantity.to_i > 0
        order = Order.first(:conditions => {:account_number => query_account_number, :login => login})
        detail = order.order_details.first(:conditions => {:id => id})
        if detail
            detail.quantity = quantity.to_i
            detail.save
        end
    end
end

def self.update_order_note query_account_number, login, order_note
    order = Order.first(:conditions => {:account_number => query_account_number, :login => login})
    order.note = order_note
    order.save
end

def self.update_order_item_note query_account_number, login, id, note
    order = Order.first(:conditions => {:account_number => query_account_number, :login => login})
    detail = order.order_details.first(:conditions => {:id => id})
    if detail
        detail.note = note
        detail.save
    end
end

def self.add_item query_account_number, login, quantity, upc1, upc2, price_code, upc_rule
    if quantity.to_i > 0
        order = Order.first(:conditions => {:account_number => query_account_number, :login => login})
        order = Order.add_order_header(query_account_number, login) if order.blank?
        if order
            item = Item.first(:conditions => ["rul31c = ? AND CONCAT(TRIM(comi1c), CONCAT(TRIM(arsb1c), 'A')) = ?", upc_rule, upc1 + upc2 + "A"],
                                                  :select => "style, color, size, pnum35, cono35, comi1c, arsb1c, ptyp35")
            price = Price.first(:conditions => {:catnwp => item.pnum35, :conowp => item.cono35, :listwp => price_code}, :select => "prcewp") unless item.blank?
            if item and price
                order_detail = OrderDetail.new(:style => item.style,
                                                                             :order_id => order.id,
                                                                             :quantity => quantity,
                                                                             :color => item.color,
                                                                             :size => item.size)
                order_detail.save

                # Return a cart item hash
                cart_contents = []
                cart_contents << {:style => item.style,
                                                    :color => item.color,
                                                    :size => item.size,
                                                    :quantity => quantity,
                                                    :name => ProItem.short_description(item.style),
                                                    :price => price.prcewp,
                                                    :type => item.ptyp35,
                                                    :upc => item.comi1c + item.arsb1c,
                                                    :id => order_detail.id}

            end
        end
    end
end

def self.order_info_update query_account_number, login, info
    order = Order.first(:conditions => {:account_number => query_account_number, :login => login})
    if order
        if info.has_key?("name")
            order.name = info[:name]
            order.address1 = info[:address1]
            order.address2 = info[:address2]
            order.address3 = info[:address3]
            order.city = info[:city]
            order.state = info[:state]
            order.zip = info[:zip]
        end
        if info.has_key?("po_number")
            order.po_number = info[:po_number]
        end
        order.save
        # where does po number go???
    end
end

def self.mailing_address query_account_number, login
    o = Order.first(:conditions => {:account_number => query_account_number, :login => login})
    {:name => o.name, :address1 => o.address1, :address2 => o.address2, :address3 => o.address3, :city => o.city, :state => o.state, :zip => o.zip} if o
end

def self.order_note query_account_number, login
    o = Order.first(:conditions => {:account_number => query_account_number, :login => login}, :select => "note")
    o.note if o
end

def self.cart_contents query_account_number, login, price_code, upc_rule
    # TODO: what to do if item changed since they put it in cart?
    # Perhaps we expire a cart after a while, but, that still is not a perfect solution.
    # Ideally here we go through each style, make sure it is still valid for the customer, and
    # check color/size as well.
    order_items = Order.first(:conditions => {:account_number => query_account_number, :login => login} )

    if order_items
        cart_contents = []
        order_items.order_details.each do |oi|

            as400_item = Item.first(:conditions => {:rul31c => upc_rule, :style => oi.style.ljust(9), :color => oi.color, :size => oi.size },
                                                :select => "pnum35, cono35, ptyp35, comi1c, arsb1c")
            price = Price.first(:conditions => {:catnwp => as400_item.pnum35, :conowp => as400_item.cono35, :listwp => price_code}, :select => "prcewp") unless as400_item.blank?

            cart_contents << {:style => oi.style,
                                                :color => oi.color,
                                                :size => oi.size,
                                                :quantity => oi.quantity,
                                                :name => ProItem.short_description(oi.style),
                                                :price => price.prcewp,
                                                :type => as400_item.ptyp35,
                                                :note => oi.note,
                                                :upc => as400_item.comi1c + as400_item.arsb1c,
                                                :id => oi.id} if as400_item and price
        end unless order_items.blank?
        cart_contents
    end
end

def self.cart_contents_count query_account_number, login
    order_items = Order.first(:conditions => {:account_number => query_account_number, :login => login} )
    count = 0
    order_items.order_details.each {|oi| count += oi.quantity } if order_items
    count
end

def self.cart_contents_total query_account_number, login, price_code, upc_rule
    order_items = Order.first(:conditions => {:account_number => query_account_number, :login => login} )
    total = 0
    order_items.order_details.each do |oi|
        as400_item = Item.first(:conditions => {:rul31c => upc_rule, :style => oi.style.ljust(9), :color => oi.color, :size => oi.size },
            :select => "pnum35, cono35, ptyp35")
        price = 0
        if !as400_item.blank?
            price = Price.first(:conditions => {:catnwp => as400_item.pnum35, :conowp => as400_item.cono35, :listwp => price_code}, :select => "prcewp")
            total += (oi.quantity * price.prcewp.to_f)
        end
    end if order_items
    total
end

def self.add_order_details query_account_number, login, items, notes = Hash.new
    result = false
    if items

        # If there is not an order record, create one. Basically we only
        # allow one open order per login at a time, and if there is
        # one already, we continue to append order_detail records to it.
        order = Order.first(:conditions => {:account_number => query_account_number, :login => login.upcase})
        order = Order.add_order_header(query_account_number, login) if order.blank?

        items.each do |key, value|
            if value.to_i > 0
                result = true
                style = key[0..8]
                color = key[9..11]
                size = key[12..14]

                order_detail = OrderDetail.new(:style => style,
                                                                             :order_id => order.id,
                                                                             :quantity => value,
                                                                             :color => color,
                                                                             :size => size,
                                                                             :note => (notes ? notes[key] : ''))
                order_detail.save
            end
        end if order
    end
    result
end

def self.submit_order query_account_number, login, price_code, distributor_number
    o = Order.first(:conditions => {:account_number => query_account_number, :login => login})

    # TODO: transaction or some error handling
    if o

        # Find all associated records we need.
        customer = Customer.first(:conditions => {:cusn05 => query_account_number}, :select => "cono05, cgp405, slmn05, list20" )
        sign_on = SignOn.first(:conditions => {:userw1 => login.upcase}, 
                                                                                     :select => "idnow1, bsnamw1, accntw1, prfdstw1, cntacw1, bsadd1w1, bsadd2w1, bsadd3w1, bscityw1, bsstcdw1, bszipw1, acctypw1")
        distributor = Distributor.first(:conditions => {:cusnp1 => distributor_number}, :select => "cnam05, emailp1")   

        if sign_on.acctypw1.strip == "DS"       
            rec = SignOn.find_by_userw1!(login)            
            webid = rec.prfdstw1            
        elsif sign_on.acctypw1.strip == "DSD"   
             rec = SignOn.find_by_userw1!(login)            
            webid = rec.prfdstw1 

        end 
        #cnt = Weboel23.count(:all,:conditions => {:act223 => mp})
        weboel23 = Weboel23.first(:conditions => {:act223 => webid}, :select => "emal23")   
        #cnt=weboel23.count     

        approval0=Weboel23.get_email_by_account0(webid)
        approval1=Weboel23.get_email_by_account1(webid)
        approval2=Weboel23.get_email_by_account2(webid)
        approval3=Weboel23.get_email_by_account3(webid)
        approval4=Weboel23.get_email_by_account4(webid)
            # weboel23 = Weboel23.each(:conditions => {:act223 => mp}, :select => "emal23")
        #approval = weboel23.emal23

        #f=File.open("/var/www/onlineordering.coastalpet.com/log/debug3.txt")
        #establish_connection "as400_#{RAILS_ENV}"          
        #f.puts "prfdstw1" 
        #f.puts rec = SignOn.find_by_userw1!(login) 
        #f.puts "type="+elephant 
        #f.puts "email="+approval0 
        #f.close            



          # s = find_by_sql ["SELECT EMAL23 emal23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = ?", distributor_number]         
          # d << { :id => s[0].emal23 } unless s.blank?


        if customer and sign_on

            as400_order_id = "WB" + o.id.to_s.rjust(8, "0")

            total = 0
            count = 0
            line = 1 # Start at 1 per Ron Hoopes 2/14/2011
            o.order_details.each do |oi|

                item = Item.first(:conditions => {:rul31c => customer.cgp405, :style => oi.style.ljust(9), :color => oi.color, :size => oi.size }, 
                                                  :select => "comi1c, arsb1c, chdt1c, pnum35, cono35, pdes35")
                price = Price.first(:conditions => {:catnwp => item.pnum35, :conowp => item.cono35, :listwp => price_code}, :select => "prcewp") unless item.blank?

                if item and price
                    WebOrderDetail.create(:conowd => customer.cono05,
                                                                :uniqwd => as400_order_id,
                                                                :linewd => line,
                                                                :itemwd => oi.style.ljust(9) + oi.color + oi.size,
                                                                :barcwd => item.comi1c.strip + item.arsb1c.strip + item.chdt1c.strip,
                                                                :altiwd => "",
                                                                :itmdwd => item.pdes35,
                                                                :qtywd => oi.quantity,
                                                                :uprcwd => price.prcewp.to_f.round_to(2),
                                                                :listwd => customer.list20,
                                                                :dtdrwd => "0",
                                                                :dcd1wd => "",
                                                                :dsc1wd => "0",
                                                                :dcd2wd => "",
                                                                :dsc2wd => "0")

                    # Create any order ITEM notes.
                    unless oi.note.blank?
                        oi.note.scan(/.{1,70}/).each_with_index do |note, index|
                            WebOrderNote.create(:conown => customer.cono05,
                                                                    :textwn => note,
                                                                    :uniqwn => as400_order_id,
                                                                    :linewn => line,
                                                                    :seqwn => index)
                        end
                    end

                    count += oi.quantity.to_i
                    total += oi.quantity.to_i * price.prcewp.to_f.round_to(2)
                    line += 1
                end
            end

            # Create any order notes.
            unless o.note.blank?
                o.note.scan(/.{1,70}/).each_with_index do |note, index|
                    WebOrderNote.create(:conown => customer.cono05,
                                                            :textwn => note,
                                                            :uniqwn => as400_order_id,
                                                            :linewn => 0,
                                                            :seqwn => index)
                end
            end

            # Coastal's definition a current century is off by one, hence the math for the date.
            as400_order_header = WebOrder.new(:conowc => customer.cono05,
                                                                                :uniqwc => as400_order_id,
                                                                                :idnowc => sign_on.idnow1,
                                                                                :namewc => o.name,
                                                                                :addr1wc => o.address1,
                                                                                :addr2wc => o.address2,
                                                                                :addr3wc => o.address3,
                                                                                :citywc => o.city,
                                                                                :statewc => o.state,
                                                                                :zipcdwc => o.zip,
                                                                                :cusnwc => query_account_number,
                                                                                :dtordwc => Utilities.to_db2_date(Date.today),
                                                                                :shpdtwc => Utilities.to_db2_date(Date.today),
                                                                                :cusowc => o.po_number.blank? ? as400_order_id : o.po_number,
                                                                                :slmnwc => customer.slmn05,
                                                                                :rulewc => customer.cgp405,
                                                                                :listwc => customer.list20,
                                                                                :valuewc => total.to_f.round_to(2),
                                                                                :statwc => "")

            if as400_order_header.save

                # Sent confirmation email, if required. Only send it for users that chose a distributor,
                # whether they had to choose one or not. We determine this by looking at the account number
                # in the sign_on and comparing it with the order number we are using for the order. If
                # that is different, it indicates that they chose a distributor.

                # These are used in the email body, key for the hash is the replacement tags, capitalized, &
                # prepended and appended with  '##', e.g. ##NAME## - and any underlines are replaced with space
                email_details = {"name" => sign_on.bsnamw1,
                                                 "order_number" => as400_order_id,
                                                 "order_total" => format('$%.2f', total),
                                                 "order_count" => count.to_s,
                                                 "order_date" => Date.today.to_s,
                                                 "distributor_name" => (distributor ? distributor.cnam05 : ""),
                                                 "distributor_contact" => "UNKNOWN",
                                                 "customer_name" => sign_on.bsnamw1,
                                                 "customer_address" => sign_on.bsadd1w1.strip + (!sign_on.bsadd2w1.blank? ? "<br>" + sign_on.bsadd2w1.strip : "") + (!sign_on.bsadd3w1.blank? ? "<br>" + sign_on.bsadd3w1.strip : ""),
                                                 "customer_city" => sign_on.bscityw1,
                                                 "customer_state" => sign_on.bsstcdw1,
                                                 "customer_zip" => sign_on.bszipw1,
                                                 "customer_contact" => sign_on.cntacw1}


                    Mailer.deliver_order_coastal_notify_email("Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation", email_details)
                # Per Dana 6/30/2012, JUST DS

                if sign_on.acctypw1.strip == "DS" or sign_on.acctypw1.strip == "DSD" 
                    # If there is no distributor email address, the mailer model will substitute in the admin's email from their settings
                    Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email(distributor ? distributor.emailp1 : "", "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation  #{approval0} #{approval1}", email_details)
                    if approval0!=""  
                        Mailer.deliver_order_confirmation_email(login, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation", email_details)
                        Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email(approval0, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation ", email_details)
                        Mailer.deliver_order_coastal_notify_email("Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation", email_details)
                        end             
                        if approval1!=""
                            Mailer.deliver_order_confirmation_email(login, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation", email_details)
                            Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email(approval1, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation  ", email_details)
                            Mailer.deliver_order_coastal_notify_email("Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation", email_details)
                            end
                        if approval2!=""
                            Mailer.deliver_order_confirmation_email(login, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation", email_details)   
                            Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email(approval2, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation ", email_details)
                            Mailer.deliver_order_coastal_notify_email("Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation", email_details)
                            end
                        if approval3!="" 
                            Mailer.deliver_order_confirmation_email(login, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation", email_details)   
                            Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email(approval3, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation  ", email_details)    
                            Mailer.deliver_order_coastal_notify_email("Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation", email_details)
                            end
                        if approval4!="" 
                            Mailer.deliver_order_confirmation_email(login, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation", email_details)   
                            Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email(approval4, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation ", email_details)
                            Mailer.deliver_order_coastal_notify_email("Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation", email_details)
                            end                 

                     Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email(weboel23 ? weboel23.emal23: "", "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "*Order Confirmation", email_details)
                     Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email("robert.kendall@coastalpet.com", "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "*Order Confirmation", email_details)

                    end

                # Al ways notify Coastal staff

                # Update the last ordered date (used for reminders)
                User.update_last_order_date(login)

                o.destroy
                as400_order_id
            end
        end
    end
end

def self.count_user_orders query_account_number, login
    count = Order.first(:conditions => {:account_number => query_account_number, :login => login})
    count.order_details.count unless count.blank? or count == 0
end

def self.reorder(order_number, login, query_account_number, upc_rule, price_code, mode)
    warnings = ""

    # If we are not in check mode, then blank out cart
    self.empty_cart(query_account_number, login) if mode != "check"

    # Get the previous order
    oo = WebOrder.get_previous_order(order_number, login)

    # Go through each line item
    oo.each do |ooi|

        # Verify it still exists in the AS400 and is same price
        # Note that this reports back a -1 if it cannot find the
        # same style+color+size option, otherwise just reports
        # price if it finds it.
        current_price = Item.check_item_exists(query_account_number, ooi[:style], ooi[:color], ooi[:size], upc_rule, price_code)

        # If item was not found, we can't add it.
        # We could spend more time to determine if it was the color, or size, or that
        # the style itself is not available, but it seems reasonable enough to
        # present it this way. Really should not be doing this "presentation" in
        # the model, but we don't have views setup for Ajax so we have to give the
        # controller the text we want rendered.
        if current_price == -1
            warnings += "SKU "+ ooi[:style].to_s + ooi[:color].to_s + ooi[:size].to_s + " is no longer available<br />"
        else
            # If price did not match, append to list of warnings
            if current_price.to_f.round_to(2) != ooi[:price].to_f.round_to(2)
                warnings += "SKU "+ ooi[:style].to_s + ooi[:color].to_s + ooi[:size].to_s + " price is " +
                    ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_currency(current_price) + " and it was " +
                    ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_currency(ooi[:price]) + "<br />"
            end
            # If not in check mode, add item to cart
            # In this case, we don't care that the price did
            # not match, we still add it.
            populate_cart(query_account_number, login, ooi[:style], ooi[:color], ooi[:size], ooi[:quantity], ooi[:line_item_note], ooi[:order_note]) if mode != "check"
        end
    end
    mode == "check" ? warnings : ""
end

def self.empty_cart query_account_number, login
    order = Order.first(:conditions => {:account_number => query_account_number, :login => login})
    order.destroy if order
end

def self.populate_cart query_account_number, login, style, color, size, quantity, note, order_note

    # If there is not an order record, create one. Basically we only
    # allow one open order per login at a time, and if there is
    # one already, we continue to append order_detail records to it.
    order = Order.first(:conditions => {:account_number => query_account_number, :login => login.upcase})
    order = Order.add_order_header(query_account_number, login) if order.blank?

    # These can be null for kits, and we don't like nulls in the database for this
    color = "" if color.blank?
    size = "" if size.blank?

    if order
        order.note = order_note # yeah we do this each time but while inefficient it works
        order.save
        order_detail = OrderDetail.new(:style => style,
                                                                     :order_id => order.id,
                                                                     :quantity => quantity,
                                                                     :color => color,
                                                                     :size => size,
                                                                     :note => note)
        order_detail.save
    end

end

private
    def self.add_order_header query_account_number, login
        # Default address info to sign_on
        sign_on = SignOn.first(:conditions => {:userw1 => login.upcase}, :select => "bsnamw1, bsadd1w1, bsadd2w1, bsadd3w1, bscityw1, bsstcdw1, bszipw1")

        if sign_on
            order = Order.new(:login => login,
                                                :account_number => query_account_number,
                                                :name => sign_on.bsnamw1,
                                                :address1 => sign_on.bsadd1w1,
                                                :address2 => sign_on.bsadd2w1,
                                                :address3 => sign_on.bsadd3w1,
                                                :city => sign_on.bscityw1,
                                                :state => sign_on.bsstcdw1,
                                                :zip => sign_on.bszipw1)
            order.save
            order
        end
    end
```

end

Comment: SignOn.find_by_userw!(login)seems to be a troublesome call to me but I don't know the scopes that you have predefined. I would not use the anti (!) to find. You can try and trace your output with logger.debug and hopefully that will give you some insight into your problem

Comment: I removed the (!) ...the error that I get in the log is NoMethodError (undefined method `prfdstw1' for nil:NilClass):

Comment: so that is telling me that you are not getting what you expect to be returned to rec. The error is saying that nothing has been found so there is no method to be called from something that "doesn't exist"

Comment: yes that is correct when I use rec = SignOn.find_by_userw1!(login) I get ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find SignOn with userw1 = bk_dsd): which is pretty much the same. I know that the rec should be there since that is the login I used. All of the Data for this is coming from an AS400

Comment: As long as you have the models setup and the method defined the active record should do the appropriate search for you. IF you would go ahead and post some more code with your model definitions and possibly the controllers I might be able to give a little bit more insight

Comment: updated with the entire model. there is a signons model also ref but I did not include it here

Comment: taking a quick peak at the code and I see that you are using many .first calls on your models in the active record. Typically you want to be passing .find with the proper parameters to better define your queries. I am going to take a better look at this when I am off work but I would take a look into some basic Active Record query standards to better formalize some of your lookups

Comment: thanks for looking at it Dan we are really stuck on this ...any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: updated on 08-02-2013

Comment: Hey man so its working currently but failing on some test cases? Have you setup the fixures and all that / ran your rake tasks to setup testing? nothing in the code is standing out as being faulty but i would be curious about those test cases

Comment: yes 8 out of 10 test cases work without any issues at all but the 2 that fail look identical at least on the surface

Comment: Is there a way to suppress the error and continue so the order will process even if it cannot send the emails?

Comment: id highly recommend http://mailcatcher.me/ it provides a way for you to capture your mail and follow it along the process. its an awesome gem :D